# SCOPE_IDENTITY() always return NULL if used with SQLBindParameter

Tags: c++, sql-server

I try to insert a data to database via ODBC sql server.
And I want to get the Id of this row back, so I use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`
Since this table has id as primary key and auto increment.
Insert function works fine, the data get inserted into database.
But when I use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` They return NULL.

so I try to use pure statement without SQLBindParameter. `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` works perfectly. Do you have any advice why I got the problem when use SQLBindParameter?

Here is my table in dB :

| [primary key] (long) Id | (nvarchar(255)) Name | (short) Position |
| --- | --- | --- |

Here is insert function with SQLBindParameter :

```
std::string name = "testname";
std::wstring ws = L"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Name], [Position]) VALUES (?,1);";

RETCODE RetCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,
            SQL_CHAR, name.length(), 0, (SQLPOINTER)name.c_str(), name.length(), NULL);

if(RetCode != SQL_SUCCESS)
{
    HandleDiagnosticRecord(hStmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, RetCode);
}

RetCode = SQLExecDirect(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)ws.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
switch(RetCode)
{
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
    break;
    //other cases
}

SQLFreeStmt(hStmt, SQL_CLOSE);
```

Here is `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` code :

```
std::wstring ws = L"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
RETCODE RetCode = SQLExecDirect(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)ws.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
switch (RetCode)
{
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
    {
        long id= -1;
        SQLLEN indPtr;
        SQLBindCol(hStmt, 1, SQL_C_LONG, &id, 0, &indPtr);

        if (SQLFetch(hStmt) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (indPtr != SQL_NULL_DATA)
            {
                std::cout << "Result id: " << characterId << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Result id: NULL " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        break;
     }
     //other cases
}
SQLFreeStmt(hStmt, SQL_CLOSE);
```

Here is insert function with out SQLBindParameter :

```
std::wstring ws = L"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Name], [Position]) VALUES ('testname', 1);";

RetCode = SQLExecDirect(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)ws.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
switch(RetCode)
{
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
    break;
    //other cases
}

SQLFreeStmt(hStmt, SQL_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Although I can't read C++, it *looks* like your `INSERT` and call to `SCOPE_IDENTITY` are in different batches/scopes; so the scope for your insert has already been lost. You should be returning the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in the same scope (hint in the name).

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your response, I try to move ``` SCOPE_IDENTITY```  to switch-case inside the ```INSERT``` function but the result is still the same.

Comment: Have you checked the `SQLRETURN` result from `SQLBindCol`? If the identity column in SQL is `int`, as opposed to `bigint`, have you tried using `SQL_C_INT` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have check the ```SQLRETURN``` of ```SQLBindCol```, The result is ```SQL_SUCCESS```. I try to using ```SQL_C_SBIGINT``` and The result is still the  same ```NULL```.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SQLBindCol(hStmt, 0,....` [columns start at 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindcol-function?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) I think, and you probably want to cast your result first `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int));` because [the return is `numeric(38,0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to use "OUTPUT" clause in order to return member of inserted item instead of calling `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`

so the completely sql command is `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Name], [Position]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id] VALUES (?,1);`